# Javascript / JQuery events vs knockout observable + subscribe

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Is there any programming scenario where JS / Jquery events need to be used while already using Knockoutjs observable variables?

Comment: This question is far too broad for SO. Separately, you're making a false distinction. KO *uses* browser events (they aren't "JS" or "jQuery" events) to deliver its two-way binding, not to mention to provide its `click` and `event` bindings.

Comment: I respectfully disagree on the too broad part. I want to know the extra functionalities of JS / JQuery events that cannot be accomplished with observable variables (in whatever way they are implemented. Thanks a lot however for sharing the knowledge on how they work!)

Comment: Fair enough. Just for reference, here's the close reason: *"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."* To me, that fits, as there are as many answers as there are use cases for events in general.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no, as you can use `ko.utils.registerEventHandler` instead, but even more technically, that's using JS events.

More to the point (I hope), you may apply jQuery events within a binding handler, but should not be doing so in your other app code. The reason is that you should not be reaching around Knockout's binding handlers to manipulate the View directly. The binding handlers exist to synchronize the View and the ViewModel. Anything you want to do to the View should be done by manipulating the ViewModel. If there is no way to modify or access the View in the way that you want via the ViewModel, you need a binding handler.

Within a binding handler, your objective is to ensure that the ViewModel and the View properly reflect each other. You may use any tools you like to achieve that.

Also note that Knockout provides an [`event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) to let your ViewModel respond to events from the View.